# jquery tabs problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I want to have two or more tabs construction on my website.

I have make a html page and javascript page with this tabs.

This is my code:
In the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#tabslinks').smartTab();
          $('#tabsrechts').smartTab();
        });
    </script>
```

And the html

```
<div id="tabslinks" class="stContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabslinks-1">
                    <h2>Tab 1<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabslinks-2">
                    <h2>Tab 2<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabslinks-3"> 
                    <h2>Tab 3<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabslinks-4">
                    <h2>Tab 4<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabslinks-1">
            <h2>Tab 1 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 1 Content here</p>           
        </div>
        <div id="tabslinks-2">
            <h2>Tab 2 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 2 Content here</p>     
        </div>                      
        <div id="tabslinks-3">
            <h2>Tab 3 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 3 Content here</p>                                 
        </div>
        <div id="tabslinks-4">
            <h2>Tab 4 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 4 Content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="tabsrechts" class="stContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabsrechts-1">
                    <h2>Tab 1<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabsrechts-2">
                    <h2>Tab 2<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabsrechts-3">    
                    <h2>Tab 3<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tabsrechts-4">
                    <h2>Tab 4<br />
                    <small>Description</small></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabsrechts-1">
            <h2>Tab 1 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 1 Content here</p>           
        </div>
        <div id="tabsrechts-2">
            <h2>Tab 2 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 2 Content here</p>     
        </div>                      
        <div id="tabsrechts-3">
            <h2>Tab 3 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 3 Content here</p>                                 
        </div>
        <div id="tabsrechts-4">
            <h2>Tab 4 Title</h2>    
            <p>Tab 4 Content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i used the jquery tab named smart tab. When you google smart tab. You can see the plugin that i use.

But no you see the problem. When i make more than 1 tabs on a page. The tabs are not working. Only 1 tab is working and the first tab is not working. Have can i make more than one tabs on 1 page?

Thanks

Comment: Here you can see my problem online: http://www.mikevierwind.nl/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning ids correctly to jQuery. Your jQuery code should look like this for it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[id^="tabslinks"]').smartTab();
});
```

The starts with selector denoted by `^` is used there to target all links having id that starts with `tabslinks` since you have link ids like this:

```
        <a href="#tabslinks-1">
                <h2>Tab 1<br />

                <small>Description</small></h2>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabslinks-2">
                <h2>Tab 2<br />
                <small>Description</small></h2>

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabslinks-3"> 
                <h2>Tab 3<br />
                <small>Description</small></h2>
            </a>
            .............
```

Alternatively, you can use a `class` to target links that you want to tabbify.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.someClass').smartTab();
});
```